# Can extension access an internal method in same assembly and be used by externals?

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code snippet assuming both these classes are in the same assembly, can an external assembly call `.DoSomethingToSomeClass();` on an `OtherClass`, or would this bark at me about security concerns?

```
public class SomeClass
{
  internal void DoSomething()
  {
    //hah!
  }
}

public static OtherClassExtension
{
  public static DoSomethingToSomeClass(this OtherClass target)
  {
    new SomeClass().DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 (offsetting) I don't see anything wrong with this question. Perhaps I'm not seeing something. Downvoter please illuminate.

Comment: An easy way to see whether a snippet of code would compile is to simply put it into LINQPad and run it. (I'm not the downvoter, btw).

Comment: The c# compiler is gonna probably bark

Comment: @StriplingWorrior, he would first need to compile the dll in order to test his theory. As far as I know you can't do that in LINQPad. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", so I suspect the downvote is for the first part or the last part.  Especially from a user who has answered over 100 questions tagged with C# :-)

Comment: Thanks everybody! I knew asking this on stackoverflow would be faster than waiting for visual studio to close my current solution or open a new one and create two projects to test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That definitely works without security concerns. Imagine the world we'd live in if it didn't: Any `public` method you write would have to call only *other* `public` methods.

Access modifiers are there to give you a say in what portions of your class (and what classes you write) are *directly accessible* by calling code. The fact there is some chain where they *could* be executed isn't relevant.

Comment: My uncertainty was related to whether being an extension would cause this to behave as though the boundary had shifted. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @Jimmy Extension methods are just methods with a little syntactic sugar thrown in, so pretty much anything that's true of ordinary methods will also be true of extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

This would **not** cause **any security concerns** on .Net's part, nor should it.  In public methods you have to be able to use internal (/private/protected) members.

The solution to the potential security issues this might cause is:  The developer making the public member has to know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

"The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members. Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly" Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I don't see why not, this should work, and you are calling a public class thats calling an internal method within it's own assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any problem with code provided, honestly.

May you can pass SomeClass like a parameter, but it's completely design decision.